# Xamarin Android Activities/ Fragments not being garbage collected

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, garbage-collection

I'm building a Xamarin Android app.
This app seems to consume more memory than the usual java/kotlin ones. I understand some memory is used by Xamarin framework itself. I did some test to check if objects are being garbage collected.

In order to test this I added destructors to different objects  `~MyClass(){ }`, put breakpoints and I could see C# objects being claimed by GC. In Fragment/Activities the destructors were not called even after `OnDestroy()`.
The simplest example to show this is a `SplashActivity` that just starts the `MainActivity` of my app.

```
  [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTop, ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait, Theme = "@style/SplashTheme")]
  public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
  {
    MyCSharpClass myObject; // this is not garbage collected
 
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        myObject = new MyCSharpClass();
     
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        StartActivity(intent);
        Finish();
    }
   
    protected override void OnDestroy() //this is called
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
    }

    ~SplashActivity() // this is not called
    {

    }
}
```

`OnDestroy` is called immediately but the destructor `~SplashActivity()` is never called.
So the fragment/activity and it's pure C# properties/fields seem to remain in memory.
I know that these are `Java.Lang.Object` types but I would expect Android and C# Garbage Collectors to work together to clear the objects.

What is the proper way to make `SplashActivity` and `myObject` to be removed from memory?

Comment: Have you tried calling `Dispose()` in the `OnDestroy` method?

Comment: After adding `Dispose()` the `~MyCSharpClass()`  destructor of `myObject`  was called :). Still not `~SplashActivity()`

Comment: @albert That's strange . I will check that .